# Grails: populate a domain with data from cross join: hql, criteria, SQL query?

Tags: grails, hql, hibernate-criteria

i'm a little bit stuck with that question.
Let's say I have a domain class:

```
class Activity {
    String activityID
    String activityDescription
    String activityType
}
```

and this other one

```
class ActivityMap {
    String activityID1
    String activityDescription1
    String activityType1
    String activityID2
    String activityDescription2
    String activityType2
}
```

I want to populate ActivityMap domain class with the result of a cross join of domain class Activity with itself, that is with result of equivalent SQL query

```
SELECT a.activityID, a.activityDescription, a.activityType, a1.activityID, a1.activityDescription, a1.activityType
FROM Activity AS a, Activity AS a1
ORDER BY a.activityID, a1.activityID;
```

I'm not sure which is the most efficient way to achieve that: using Criteria, HQL or embedded SQL query, as resulting set of data may be quite large (300-50+ Activity occurrences, 250k result rows expected)?

Any suggestions/tip, example?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: excuse me, but I think it's not a good solution? There are lots of redundant data if you save the ActivityMap like that. why not only save activityID1 and activityID2?

Comment: The fact is that I need to store somo fields to make some calculations on them. I know there will be redundant data, but regarding the volume of information I'll manage, it will be better to store it in a temporary domain class/table than to access parent tables. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate have problems with queries returning such large results, even if there is 10k+ result rows. So 250k rows eats all your memory and cpu.

I recommend you to try with native SQL query, furthermore you not expecting actual results, only `INSERT ... SELECT`

Comment: Thanks, Igor, for your recommendation as I actually feel more comfortable with SQL! Anyway, I'll give other possibilities a chance and try to post here the results.
Regards

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use max and offset parameters appended to the end of the findAll. In that case, how could I inject the whole set of data in the resulting domain class?